# Runner technique to combine two equal Linked Lists of general size

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

2
So, I am facing a doubt here.

I was reading the book Cracking the coding Interview. The following text is written over there.

Suppose you had a linked list a1->a2....->an->b1->b2....bn, and you want to rearrange it into a1->b1->a2->b2->.....an->bn. You don't know the length of the linked list but all you know is that it is an even number.

(Here both the linked lists are of the same length)

You could have one pointer p1 (fast pointer) move every two elements for every one move that p2 makes. When p1 hits the end of the linked list, p2 will be at the endpoint. Then, move p1 back to the front and begin "weaving" the elements. On each iteration, p2 selects an element and inserts it after p1.

I don't understand how when p1 hits the end of the linked list, p2 will be at the midpoint. This is how I am imagining it if n=3 (length = 6). Each step below represents an iteration.

I have tried with linked listed consisting of 4 elements and was successful in achieving the result. However, I can't solve for the general case, because my pointers get dangly. Would it be possible to provide code for the problem in python, I am stuck. And this is my code:

```
def runner_technique_ex(self, head):
    """
    Assume the length of the ll that we will run thru will be even
    :param head:
    :return:
    """
    slow = head
    fast = head.next
    while fast.next is not None:
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next.next

    fast = head
    slow = slow.next
    while slow.next is not None:
        tempSlow = slow
        tempFast = fast.next
        fast.next = tempSlow
        slow = slow.next
        tempSlow.next = tempFast
        tempFast.next = slow
```

Comment: _"Would it be possible to provide code for the problem in python"_ -- first, Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. You are expected to post your work, showing what you've tried so far, and keep your question _specific_ to what in particular you're having trouble with. Second, if you are particular about the language you want your question and answer to be considered in, you need to include that language as a tag on your question.

Comment: Beyond all that, it is not even clear in your question what the problem is. I find it patently obvious that if you are traversing a list of length M where M = 2 * N, with one pointer advancing two nodes (i.e. skipping one) each time another pointer advances one, that the first pointer will move through the list twice as quickly as the second, and thus when the first reaches the end, the second will have only gotten halfway (one going twice the speed as the other, is the same as the other going half the speed as the first).

Comment: @PeterDuniho As you can see, I have achieved the moment where the slow pointer is in the middle and the fast pointer is in the beginning. However, I get confused with the pointers inside the second while loop

Comment: You will likely get less interest in your question, due to the lack of a [mcve]. That said: in the code you posted, I would suggest that the very last line of code should be removed, and that you should add statements to advance your `fast` and `slow` pointers. I would also not use the names `fast` and `slow` in the second loop, because those names no longer describe the pointers. Finally, do not underestimate the usefulness of pencil and paper, to manually trace through your algorithm, and draw diagrams showing the state of your list at each statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out after some struggle

```
def runner_technique_ex(self, head):
    """
    Assume the length of the ll that we will run thru will be even
    :param head:
    :return:
    """
    slow = head
    fast = head.next
    while fast.next is not None:
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next.next

    fast = head
    slow = slow.next

    newHead = Node(fast.data)
    newHeadExtraPointer = newHead
    newHead.next = Node(slow.data)

    newHead = newHead.next
    while slow.next is not None:

        fast = fast.next
        slow = slow.next

        fastNextNode = Node(fast.data)
        slowNextNode = Node(slow.data)

        fastNextNode.next = slowNextNode
        newHead.next = fastNextNode
        newHead = fastNextNode.next

    return newHeadExtraPointer
```